# New Entra External ID issuer not valid in API Managment

Tags: azure-api-management, microsoft-entra-external-id

We are using Entra External ID for customers for an upcoming service and today the issuer ("iss") claim had changed, causing validate-azure-ad-token in our API Management to fail, returning an "Issuer is not valid" message and 401.

The format used to be ({tenantId} is a GUID):

> `"iss": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/v2.0",`

but now it is

> `"iss": "https://{tenantId}.ciamlogin.com/{tenantId}/v2.0",`

I tried changing the tenant-id property of validate-azure-ad-token policy from `"{tenantId}"` (again, this is a GUID) to `"{tenantId}.ciamlogin.com"`, but it did not work, as it was longer than 36 characters (there is no such limitation mentioned in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/validate-azure-ad-token-policy#policy-statement). Changing tenant-id to `"mytenant.ciamlogin.com"` did not help either.

Is there anything else I can try, or is this an issue that needs to be fixed in either APIM or Entra?